# Extend a centered element to one side

Tags: html, css

I have a header that is centered but I'd like the bottom border to extend all the way to the left of the screen but preserve the max-width of the header.

**Example 1:**
Screen width is 1400px
Header width is 1200px (starting at left: 100px, ending at left:1300px)
Border width is 1300px (starting at left:0, ending at left:1300px)

**Example 2:**
Screen width is 100px
Header width is 100px
Border width is 100px

**Code:**

```
<header>
    ...
</header>

header {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You can not have a border extend beyond the dimensions of the element itself. Using a positioned pseudo-element to simulate the effect is probably the best way to go about this.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is to warp the content of the header (the 1200px) part into another div, so your header becomes 100% width and the container in it has the max width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border will not work, try something like:

```
header {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
}
```